# Can I add and enable the DNS service on a new server without disturbing the rest of the network?

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system

I have a network which include a windows 2003 DCHP and DNS server.

I am planning on replacing this server with a more powerful box. (windows 2008 standard)

I want to be able to set up the active diretory on this new box, but to do so means that I need to enable DNS on this new box. I am not going to enable dchp server on this new box for the time being, but will adding this new dns server upset the existing network?

Do I need to completely isolate this new server first?

Comment: If the new 2008 box's AD install is another DC for the existing domain, it doesn't need DNS installed on it. It can use the existing DNS server. You can then add DNS later, when you're ready to decommission the old server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, presumably nothing is currently set to use that server for lookups you should have no impact whatsoever.

Comment: Thats what I think too, just checking as I dont want to take a netowrk down over the weekend.  I'd like to keep it attach though, so that I can continue to setup from home over then weekend.